# MKMapView stops responding on iDevice

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Please forgive me if this question is a bit long but not sure how to ask using less information.

I am using XCode 5.1.1 and an iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1

I have an app that uses an SQLite3 database with a number of tables. The user can access these via a number of ways. Among them is " Find nearby".
This is done for multi tables.
The MKMapView is loaded successfuly,
pins showing locations & user location display.
at first I can tap a pin and it will load the next View controller which is a detail view but after some number of uses the MKMapView stops responding at all. I can not scroll the map and tapping a pin gets no action.
Once one MKMapView stops responding none of the others work either. I can't duplicate this in the sim & if I connect the device and run it connected it works as expected so no error messages. Leaving the device connected rebuilds the app and reloads on the device which prevents the failure.

The MKMapView is the only thing loaded into the View.
User interaction for the View is unchecked in IB.
All user interaction functions for the MKMapView are checked.
The .m is set as MKMapViewDelegate.

I've run out of ideas. And checked everything that has been suggested by web searchs. Any suggestions are appreciated. I can post code if there are any specific requests

Thanks for any help

After some farther testing I've discovered that MKMapView stops responding if the iDevice is moving & begins to respond once it stops.

Comment: "User interaction for the View is unchecked in IB" - Whoa whoa whoa. If a view's user interaction is unchecked, you can't interact with its subviews either. This should _checked_, not unchecked. The map view should _never_ have been interactive; the fact that it is makes me think that you've got an extra map view or something.

Comment: Checked or unchecked. The behavior is the same. I've tried it both ways. One of the things I read in one of my web searches suggested the View being checked overruled the WebView.

Comment: OKay I've found and fixed the problem the update follows:

The problem was that I was doing all the work to produce annotations including region in the didUpdateUserLocation method. This caused the MKMapView to constantly update and prevent any access to the map or pins. That is why it did not fail in the sim nor when the device was connected to debugger.

The fix was to move all that code to the viewDidAppear method and now the map view loads only once no matter wheather the device is moving or not.

Comment: Very nice! You should post this as an answer, as it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

I've found and fixed the problem the update follows: The problem was that I was doing all the work to produce annotations including region in the `didUpdateUserLocation` method. This caused the `MKMapView` to constantly update and prevent any access to the map or pins. That is why it did not fail in the sim nor when the device was connected to debugger. The fix was to move all that code to the `viewDidAppear:` method and now the map view loads only once no matter whether the device is moving or not.